# unwanted space before and after nested html table using Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an html table nested in an html table cell. I want the nested table to use the full size of the cell it is nested in. When I use firefox or google chrome I get the result I want but when I use Internet Explorer 8 (even if I use td style="height="100%") the height of the nested cell depends on it's content. As a result I get whitespace before and after my nested table. Here is a simple html that will reproduce the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body, html, table{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table, td, th {border:#000 medium solid}
</style>
<body>
<table>
   <tr>
    <th style="margin:0;padding:0;height:100;">
    <table><tr><th style="height:100%">nested cell</th></tr></table>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For what it is worth, these days it is considered better design to use <DIV> and the CSS box model for layout.  More flexible and easier to control.

Comment: Thanks tom. But since the page I have is allready designed with tables and I don't have the time to change everything I was wondering if there was a quick solution to my problem. Besides, theoritically, I should be able to take control of by tables' display with css, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem, you have specified `<th style="margin:0;padding:0;height:100;">` in inline CSS style for you `th` inside your main `table`.

This should solve you problem, try using `height:100%;` instead.

**EDIT:**

To get rid of you extra space that requires in IE8 to scroll down you page, you can remove you border and add `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` to you main table.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body, html, table{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
</style>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
    <th style="margin:0px;padding:0px;height:100%;">
    <table><tr><th>nested cell</th></tr></table>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Again, thanks Fabio! Indeed it works! I think I can do without the borders. Besides I only used them in order to make the problem visible in the first place.

Comment: @John: Glad to help. I recommend to use CSS next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using attached code worked for me for both IE and FF but had to remove the borders as they are handled differently by IE and FF

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body, html, table{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table{border:#000 0px solid}
</style>
<body>
<table style="background:#063"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <tr>
    <th style="margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;">
    <table style="background:#0FF;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><th style="height:100%">nested cell</th></tr></table>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<th>`, you have "height:100;" instead of "height:100%;" - missing the "%"

Comment: He meant that when he used "height:100%;" Firefox had the desired effect, but IE8 added some extra space.

Comment: Right - but he misspelled his css. If I use the code exactly as he posted it (without the % sign) I see the behavior he describes. When I add the % sign, I see the behavior he wants.

Comment: Yes. He misspelled his CSS, i was going to writing the same as you did, but then i realized what he meant. But if you add the %, the cell will take all available space in the Table, with IE8 the same happens, but IE8 adds some extra space requiring you to scroll down your page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry I didn't notice this. Have you any ideas about how I can get rid of the extra space than requires to scroll down (as Fabio mentioned?)

Comment: @John: Thats what i'm trying to do now ;)

Comment: When I view a page with you html exactly as posted, I don;t see any extra space. The table and cell take up the entire screen, with no scroll bars. If I switch IE8 to compatibility view, then I see some scrolling. Fix all your margin and padding styles to be "0px" instead of "0" and this should go away.

Comment: @John: If don't need borders on your table. Have a look at my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

try just adding  `th{height:100%}`   to your css style

Comment: yes you can take complete control of your tables using css, if you can use id="" or class="" inside the element then you can get even better control.

Answer (score 0):

```
<th style="margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;">
```

instead of

```
<th style="margin:0;padding:0;height:100;">
```